# convert *.txt content to codepage 850 OEM

Tags: php, character-encoding, file-conversion, codepages

I wrote a little php-script to create a txt-file.
Now I have to convert the character set to CP 850 OEM.
Does anyone have a tip , what the syntax has to look like?

Comment: Could you provide your code?

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = mb_convert_encoding($str, "CP850");
```